# は as sentence final particle

Tags: sentence-final-particles

I meant to gather more examples before posting this question, but here we go. These are some lines out of various Ghibli movies I saw last weekend.

```
わからないは - when asked to take a guess about something
いないは - after looking for someone in a specific place
```

I realize this is casual and may not be strictly grammatically correct. Still I wonder what's the reasoning behind these type of sentences. It's not difficult to understand what they mean, but why は? How would a native speaker justify the particle? And if someone can tie it to some formally correct version of the sentences that would be great!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a sentence-final particle, it's `わ`, not `は`.  See more about in [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/244/78) post and [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2886/78) post.

Comment: Thank you, simple as that. :) I have not come across わ as a particle in my studies yet.

Comment: @gibbon, neither did I, it was something I just learned from hearing people use it :)